# $n+1$ polynomials in $n$ variables are algebraically dependent

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

I was reading [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/189191/137264) on MO and the proof is pretty straightforward for two polynomials $f,g$ in $K[x]$ ($K$ a field), so I wondered about how it generalises to $n$ variables and this led to the following questions:

1. Do we even need for $K$ to be a field? Doesn't this exact proof hold for $R[x]$ ($R$ an integral domain) word for word? The submodule of polynomials of degree $\leq N$ has rank $N+1$, so the same proof should work, shouldn't it?
2. If the above is true, could we generalise to $n+1$ polynomials in $n$ variables inductively, i.e. the following way

> Let $f_0,\dots,f_n$ be polynomials in $K[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ (instead of $K$ we could have any integral domain $A$ here) and let $R=K[x_2,\dots,x_n]$, that is identify $K[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ with $R[t]$. The $f_0,\dots,f_n$ are algebraically dependent as elements of $R[t]$ and therefore algebraically dependent over $K$ as well.

3. If the above proof is not correct, how do we generalise to $n$ variables? By using total degree?

Edit: Now that I think about it, my proof probably doesn't work, since even if $f_0,\dots,f_n$ are algebraically dependent as elements of $R[t]$, they don't necessarily have to be algebraically dependent as elements of $K[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ (since the polynomial $F$ that annihilates them has coefficients in $R$ and not $K$). Is there a way of repairing this?

Addendum: On a related note, I've found something interesting in [an another answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/41539/137264) on MO. It says that a set of polynomials $f_1,…,f_n$ is algebraically independent if and only if the form $df_1\wedge\cdots\wedge df_n$ is non-vanishing. Does anyone have a reference to a proof of this? I am taking a manifolds course at the moment, so this result grabbed my attention since I learned about differential forms just recently, but the proof sketch on MO doesn't say anything to me and I'd like to see something more elementary/thorough.

Comment: Integral domains are essentially fields, for the purpose of this question. 

Comment: @ThomasAndrews so all of the above is correct? Alright, great.

Comment: I didn’t say anything about “all of the above.” I just was commenting on part 1.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews you're right, I was overhasty.

Comment: For part one you can use that every integral domain can be embedded into a field, namely its quotient field. Then the polynomials are linearly dependent over the quotient field and hence also over the original integral domain (just multiply through by the product of the divisors of the coefficients in the quotient field).